# Ingresar Login mediante URL con parametros - Angular

Tags: angular, login, url, embebido, parametros

tengo un sistema donde el usuario esta logeado y una pagina embebida echa en Angular de otro proveedor. Tengo user y pass y necesito que mediante un link ingrese directamente al home sin tener que ingresar los accesos manualmente algo asi: (https//:www.prueba.com/home?use=admin&pass=123) he probado pero no doy. ¿Alguno tiene alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: Primero responde la pregunta del millón. Ambas aplicaciones están en el mismo dominio o están en dominios diferentes??

Comment: Están en diferentes dominios, la página embebida es otro sistema y lo que quiero es evitar doble login intentando hacerlo mediante la Url

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer se llama [Single Sign On (SSO)](https://codeburst.io/building-a-simple-single-sign-on-sso-server-and-solution-from-scratch-in-node-js-ea6ee5fdf340): El principio de funcionamiento básico en el que funciona `SSO` es que puede iniciar sesión en un sistema en un grupo de aplicaciones multisistema y estar autorizado en todos los demás sistemas sin tener que iniciar sesión nuevamente, incluido el inicio de sesión único y el cierre de sesión único.

El link que te acabo de poner tiene dos inconvenientes, para que funcione correctamente:

1. Necesita de un un [certificado de seguridad](https://salvatorelab.com/2014/02/certificado-ssl-en-node-js-y-express/).
2. Es recomendable que las aplicaciones estén en el mismo dominio.

Debido a ello [cito esta publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43635077/6009099):

> Como tus aplicaciones se ejecutan en diferentes dominios, no puedes
>   compartir cookies entre esas APLICACIONES que se ejecutan en la
>   máquina del cliente para validar al usuario. Entonces, de alguna
>   manera, la información debe compartirse en el servidor.
>
> La solución más simple que viene a mi mente es:
>
> 1. Tener una sesión compartida para todos los servidores.
> 2. Tener dominio de autenticación específico y redirige a los usuarios allí cuando se necesita autenticación. Autentique al usuario allí y
>      configure una cookie de sesión o token lo que quiera.
> 3. Siempre que alguna aplicación tuya necesite autenticación, redirígela al dominio de autenticación. La cookie de autenticación se
>      servirá al dominio de autenticación, así como al dominio de
>      referencia. Al ver que ya está validado, el servidor de autenticación
>      puede redirigirlo a la aplicación original con el Id. De sesión
>      adecuado, que se configurará como cookie para ese dominio.
> 4. Si no se autentica, se le pedirá al usuario que se autentique en el servidor de autenticación y luego se realizará la redirección.
> 5. Con pequeños cambios, puede lograr esto usando tokens y sin necesidad de sesiones compartidas.
>
> Valide los estados correctamente antes de implementarlo. Más estados
>   en su mecanismo significa más posibilidades de errores y posibles
>   ataques.
>
> Considere mover sus aplicaciones en el mismo subdominio. Si el
>   mecanismo de autenticación es el mismo, todos saben que todas las
>   aplicaciones pertenecen a la misma compañía. También será más fácil
>   para las personas recordar varios subdominios en el mismo dominio en
>   lugar de recordar todos los dominios diferentes.

Comment: Gracias abrahamhs, si eso es lo que necesito hoy voy a revisar esto que me comentas, creo que para este caso usaré un token, cuando quede resuelto publico la solución. Saludos

Comment: Como veras esto es mucho del lado del `server`, porque una configuración así es de `servidores de aplicaciones` como `tomcat`, `glassfish`, `IIS`, `apache` o en este caso `express`, es por eso que los links que te puse hacen referencia a `node.js` con `express` y no tanto a `angular`

Answer (score 0):

te comparto cómo podrías hacer el proceso.

*En el app-routing.module.ts o donde hagas el manejo de tus rutas (direccionamientos), tendrías que poner algo como lo siguiente, si estas usando lazy loading tambien va a funcionar:*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: ':id', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Posteriormente en tu loginComponent tener lo siguiente:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(this.router.url);
      if (params['id'] !== undefined && params['id'] === 'home' && this.router.url.startsWith('/home?')) {
        this.ingresar(this.router.url);
      } else if (params['id'] === undefined || params['id'] === 'home') {
        this.ingresar();
      } else {
        console.log();
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    });
  }


  ingresar(uri?) {
    if (uri !== undefined) {
      let datos = uri.split(/[?]/g)[1];
      datos = datos.split(/[&]/g);
      const json = { user: null, pass: null };
      for (const dato of datos) {
        if (dato.startsWith('user')) {
          json.user = dato.split(/[=]/g)[1];
        } else if (dato.startsWith('pass')) {
          json.pass = dato.split('=')[1];
        }
      }
      console.log(json);
    }
  }
}
```

Te recomiendo que tengas el hash(#) activo, ya que en producción podría presentarte fallos si no lo está, debido a que tu servidor necesita identificar donde inicia el llamado al proyecto.

Ya depende de ti realizar el resto de los ajustes y validaciones que requieras.

Espero haber sido de ayuda.